# Is it possible to insert animations into Microsoft Office Word 2010 Documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010, animated-gif

I was just wondering if I could insert gif animations into MS Office Word 2010 documents.

Comment: In order to be able to consider answering your question....please provide more input...what type of GIF, where is it from, do you have a gif player program installed on your computer ????

Comment: What happens when you try doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this question on [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-to-display-an-animated-gif-in-word-2010/0d2ae174-a9a3-4c85-bfab-096678becfb5) you can insert the animation into an MS Word 2010 document, but it will only show the first frame (I'm guessing this is because they expect word processors only to produce static documents at the end of the day that can be printed out).

However, if you set it as a webpage document and view it as a webpage the gif will be animated.

So, you can't really do this as you would like, but it is (sort of) possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same question. But alas, It's not possible. the gif will not play. So the alternative solution is Google docs. Google Docs will act as MS Word and play tha gif file. Good luck. But when you download that file as ms word document, it will not play the gif.